# How server verifies JWT token

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

How does the server validate the JWT token?

Where is it stored?

How does the token expire after specific days?

On the client side, I store the token and send it to each query. But what's happening on the server side?

It could do with some entry that works

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a JWT expert, so if some of what I write is wrong, I'm very happy to be corrected.

1) When distributing the JWT, the server will sign it using a private key. The private key is top secret, and must be stored securely on the server. This signature can then be verified using a public key, which confirms that this token was indeed signed by the server (using the top secret private key). The public key is not necessarily secret and can be widely distributed to anyone who needs to verify that the token was signed by that server.

2) The JWT does not really need to be stored anywhere on the server, as the server can verify that it's a valid token whenever it receives it. As the server is also likely to generate JWT, some servers will use a cache to store generated and valid JWT to increase performance. So in short, the JWT does not need to be stored by the server.

3) The JWT contains lots of data, including an expiration time (or time when it was created, and duration for how long it's valid). In addition to verifying the token using the public key, the server will discard valid tokens that have expired.

4) Before processing your request, the server will at minimum use the public key to verify that the token is genuine and check the expiration time. If it passes those tests, the server might also do additional checks with the data stored in the JWT before processing your request. These checks might include checking if your user ID has permission to access the data you are trying to access, check if you're located in a country to has access to the data, and so on. It can change wildly from a case to case basis.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit of a broad question. I'll try to answer some specific points though.

> How does the server validate the JWT token?

JWTs are typically digitally signed.
The token server signs the token using either symmetric or asymmetric cryptography.
The resource server validates the token by checking the signature against the symmetric key or public key.

> Where is it stored?

This is up to the client.
In the case of a single page application, the client can store the token in local or session storage.

> How does the token expire after specific days?

A JWT always has an expiry time, set in the token when it is created.
And since the token is signed, this time cannot be changed by someone without the key.
The resource server must check the expiry time after validating the signature.

Comment: What is the process of comparing the token sent from the customer? Is it somewhere saved on the server and involves a comparison?

Comment: It involves various checks after the cryptographic integrity is checked.. I would suggest you use a JWT library and not worry too much about the details.

Comment: What happens to the tokens when the server is restarted? They lost? How is the token assigned to the user if it is not stored in the dancyh database?

Comment: Token storage on the client is left to them. The server does not need to worry about that. The signing keys will still be the same so the signatures will be valid after a restart too.

Comment: @Imposoft: Nothing happens when the server restarts. Usually your server would call the well known endpoint of the identity server to obtain the key to verify the signature (or you provide it in your application, depends on implementation and configuration). Unless this encryption key changes, the token will remain valid until its expiry date. Some middlewares (i.e. IdentityServer4) provide the revocation of tokens (only when using reference (aka opaque) token, not jwt itself)